# Laravel Eloquent Relationship Chain

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm building a simple notification system. 
I'm able to get the logged in users notifications via `Auth::user()->notifications` but my end goal is to also grab the users info the notification is from.

I'm hoping for an end result of

```
foreach( Auth::user()->notifications AS $n)
{
    echo $n->from->username;
}
```

currently this throws a "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

Notification table;

```
id
user_id - notification for this user
from_user_id - notification from this user
```

User.php;

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Notification', 'user_id', 'id')->orderBy('notifications.id','desc');
}

public function notificationsUnread()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Notification', 'user_id', 'id')->where('notifications.seen',null)->orderBy('notifications.id','desc');
}
```

Notification.php;

```
public function to()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}

public function from()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'from_user_id');
}
```

Comment: unsure what you're problem really is, can you elaborate or show what's not working for you?

Comment: I'm unable to attach the user information the notification is from i.e. the username of the user the notification is from. I updated my question.

Comment: try `Notification->from;`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have a foreign key set in the table notifications; Then a user can have a notif. and many at the same time. A notif. belongs to a user and many notif. can belong to a user. So on the Notification model you set up the relationship belongsTo like so;

Foreign key:

```
$table->foreign('from')->refrences('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

then the relationship:

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then from the controller you can get users info like so;

```
$userName= Notification::users()->name;
```

In your case, you're pointing it wrong inreturn you will get only the relationship type instead of data object, since you are calling `from` like a non method. You should do something like this:

```
foreach( Auth::user()->notifications AS $n)
{
    echo $n->from()->username;
}
```